# Wrapping powershell around ruby

Tags: ruby, powershell, devops

I have a mixed environment of Linux and Windows, but build scripts are created in Ruby. I am trying to do some changes on each web server that involves PSRemoting but looks like I have some issue converting string to powershell command:

```
puts "%x{ powershell.exe invoke-command  -computername #{server} -scriptblock { $oldpath = #{current_iis_site_folder}; $newpath = #{new_site_folder}; Get-ChildItem -Path $oldpath -Recurse | where {($_.FullName -notmatch $oldpath.replace('\\','\\\\')) -or ($_.FullName -notmatch $newpath.replace('\\','\\\\'))}} }.strip.downcase"

%x{ powershell.exe invoke-command  -computername #{server} -scriptblock { $oldpath = #{current_iis_site_folder}; $newpath = #{new_site_folder}; Get-ChildItem -Path $oldpath -Recurse | where {$_.FullName -notmatch "corehr"}} }.strip.downcase
```

The product of this is:

```
%x{ powershell.exe invoke-command  -computername iistest.neogov.net -scriptblock { $oldpath = c:\webdata\corehr; $newpath = c:\webdata\corehr\07241439; Get-ChildItem -Path $oldpath -Recurse | where {($_.FullName -notmatch $oldpath.replace('\','\\')) -or ($_.FullName -notmatch $newpath.replace('\','\\'))}} }.strip.downcase
```

> 'where-object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

If I replace `where-object` with just `where` then error is different:

> Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace
>
> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)

I think pipe (`|`) might be confusing ruby interpreter but not sure how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be only part of the Anwser, but for CMD the escape character for | is  ^, if use ^| then the output is different but not correct yet (i did change the code somewhat to make it work so you might want to copy and adjust mine), Ruby might use the same or something different i am not sure but i believe youre on the right track.

```
powershell.exe -command {invoke-command  -scriptblock {$oldpath = "C:\Users\...\corehr"; $newpath = "C:\Users\...\corehr\07241439"; Get-ChildItem -Path $oldpath -Recurse | where {($_.FullName -notmatch $oldpath.replace('\','\\')) -or ($_.FullName -notmatch $newpath.replace('\','\\'))}}}
```

With CMD Results in

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

But it in powershell it gave:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\...\corehr


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                        
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                        
d----         24-7-2017     15:41            test1                                                       
d----         24-7-2017     15:41            test2
```

Replacing | with ^| results in

```
invoke-command -scriptblock {$oldpath = C:\Users\...\corehr; $newpath = C:
\Users\...\corehr\07241439; Get-ChildItem -Path $oldpath -Recurse | where
{($_.FullName -notmatch $oldpath.replace('\','\\')) -or ($_.FullName -notmatch
$newpath.replace('\','\\'))}}
```

Now it thinks the -command input is a string? but as you can see, the pipe character is correctly displayed in this output.

Comment: YES ! Thank you, so ^ is the escape key for | ... So frustrating that these small things take away so much time :(